# How should I handle connection timeouts in Ruby Sequel?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rack, sequel

I'm using Sequel to talk to a MySQL database from a Rack webapp.  Sometimes, the application sits idle long enough that it exceeds `wait_timeout` on the server (which we've left at the default 8 hours).  The exception suggests we can enable `autoReconnect`, but apparently that's [not encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667289/why-does-autoreconnect-true-not-seem-to-work).  Anyway, in that case, I'd still get an exception, and have to retry the operation.

If `autoReconnect` is a bad pattern, what pattern should I use?  What I want to do is

```
DB["myDB"].pool.hold do | conn |
  ... do stuff
end
```

but of course that throws if the connection is stale.  I can wrap the whole thing a begin-rescue and just try again, but if I have a large pool, I could end up retrying 10 or 20 times before I find one that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possible solutions:

1) Increase the wait_timeout.

2) Use a cron job so that a connection is used more often than wait_timeout.

3) Use the connection_validation extension, which transparently handles reconnects if a disconnect is detected.

Comment: It looks like connection_validator was added recently -- I'll have to update my version to try it, but it sounds like exactly what I was in the market for.