# Gradle SonarQube Plugin Analysis fails at the very end with MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

We have a multi-project Gradle build (7 projects). I am using the just released Gradle SonarQube plugin (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle). Our Sonar 5.1.1 instance is on a remote host (Azure VM). MySQL database with default settings (16M Query Cache, 512MB Innodb buffer). We are analysing only Java source. Everything seems to work fine - and infact, all the reports are sent to Sonar and committed (i.e we can see the analysis results). But the Gradle task does not exit cleanly.

```
10:21:40.236 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 89ms, dir size=165 KB
10:21:40.341 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 105ms, zip size=166 KB
10:21:40.341 DEBUG - Publish results
10:21:40.722 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 381ms
10:21:40.722 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://104.45.20.156:9000/sonar/dashboard/index/adm
10:21:40.722 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
10:21:40.723 DEBUG - Post-jobs : 
10:21:40.723 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@f7904ea[id=1770,key=adm,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-adm
10:37:50.391 ERROR - JDBC commit failed
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1611) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146) ~[sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commit(JpaDatabaseSession.java:83) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commitAndClose(JpaDatabaseSession.java:69) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.stop(JpaDatabaseSession.java:64) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.stop(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:96) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.stop(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:88) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.stop(AbstractBehavior.java:179) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.stop(Stored.java:141) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.stop(Stored.java:118) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1047) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:802) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:118) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:107) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch8742162731148716300.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:50) [gradle-sonarqube-plugin-1.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75) [gradle-base-services-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86) [gradle-core-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169) [gradle-base-services-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23) [gradle-launcher-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45-internal]
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30) [gradle-wrapper.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127) [gradle-wrapper.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56) [gradle-wrapper.jar:2.2.1]
10:37:50.393 WARN  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
10:37:50.393 ERROR - Already closed.
:sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to execute Sonar

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot release connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.aggressiveRelease(ConnectionManager.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.afterTransaction(ConnectionManager.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commit(JpaDatabaseSession.java:83)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.commitAndClose(JpaDatabaseSession.java:69)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.stop(JpaDatabaseSession.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.stop(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.stop(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:88)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.stop(AbstractBehavior.java:179)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.stop(Stored.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.stop(Stored.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1047)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:802)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:107)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.closeConnection(ConnectionManager.java:474)
    ... 85 more

BUILD FAILED
```

We are running with -Dsonar.verbose=true and -Dsonar.host.url and -Dsonar.jdbc.url.

Our sonar settings inside Gradle look like this :

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.scm.provider", "git"

        property "java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"

        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "----"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "----"
    }
}
```

We have exlusion filters set on the remote Sonar instance and force auth is false (default).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is related to Gradle SQ Plugin. Do you have other SQ analysis connected to the same DB that use for example Maven SQ Plugin or SQ Runner and that don't have the issue?
Also do you know the value of parameter 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout'?

Comment: No, we don't. This is the first time we are using Sonar for anything. Fresh installation and it's the first time we are trying this out (We are moving from just using Jacoco/Jenkins to Sonar+Jacoco). The value of innodb_lock_wait_timeout is 50s which is the default. Do you think we should try with a higher value? Thanks.

Comment: Increasing innodb_lock_wait_timeout did not help us :(

Comment: A related question - is the sonar-runner plugin still valid?

Comment: Maybe you can try to add autoReconnect parameter to the JDBC URL. But this doesn't seem to work for all cases. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667289/why-does-autoreconnect-true-not-seem-to-work

Comment: Adding this reconnect parameter did not work. We are still stuck :(

Comment: Adding the autorc param did not work for us. We are stuck here and cannot proceed since our CI hangs on the job above. We have a thread dump to share, but unable to attach to this post...

Comment: We have noticed a pattern. The probem seems to occure when this : 
13:42:06.078 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-$project takes longer than 5 minutes. For all other projects the gradle sonarqube tasks completes and exits without the "hang"